# why some unity source code assign null has a cast operation？

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Recently,i found some code like  `Material s_DefaultUI = (Material) null;` in Unity Graphic source code.But i don`t know why there has a cast operation.what's the benefit ?Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this the original source code, or code from a decompiler? If it's the one [here](https://github.com/jamesjlinden/unity-decompiled/blob/master/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Graphic.cs), then it might just be some decompiler artifact. _(Edit: Removed the suggestion that it might be `var s_DefaultUI = (Material)null;` since it's field in that code, so couldn't be var)._

Comment: it from jetbrains rider decompiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting `null` to a nullable type, in a assignment to a explicitly typed variable, doesn't do anything and doesn't change anything, it's the same as not casting it at all, the only times when casting null to a type has a "*benefit*" is when:

1) You have multiple signatures of the same method which have different nullable types on the same position, e.g.:

```
void CheckIfNull(string s);

void CheckIfNull(Material m);
```

In this case, doing `CheckIfNull(null)` won't work because, it doesn't know to which sig the specified `null` should be passed to, so doing `CheckIfNull((Material)null)` will solve the issue.

2) If you have a value type which accepts a nullable type via a explicit conversion, e.g.:

```
struct StructA
{
    public StructA(object obj) { }

    public static explicit operator StructA(object obj)
    {
        return new StructA(obj);
    }
}

void Stuff()
{
    StructA myStruct = (StructA)null;
}
```

3) When using a implicitly typed variable, if `s_DefaultUI` was a `var` you would need to cast the `null` because, `var` is a auto type so it wouldn't know what the provided `null`'s *type* is.

Other then that, AFAIK, there is no point in casting a null to a type, especially to a class type.